# JClouds Logging Error

Tags: jclouds

I have the code below - can someone tell me the cause of the error?

```
`String provider = "openstack-nova";
 String username = "admin:admin";
 String credential = "luel2005";
 String endpoint = "httpenter code here://192.168.2.100:5000/v2.0/";
 ContextBuilder contextBuilder = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider).credentials(username, credential).endpoint(endpoint);`
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.jclouds.providers.ProviderMetadata: Provider org.jclouds.aws.route53.AWSRoute53ProviderMetadata could not be instantiated: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection$Builder.addAll(ImmutableCollection.java:342)
```

Answer (score 1):

From first glance, the endpoint that you are using to create the Context appears to be malformed:

```
String endpoint = "httpenter code here://192.168.2.100:5000/v2.0/";
```

Try removing the "enter code here" from that String and give it another try. For further reference, check out the jclouds [OpenStack QuickStart](http://jclouds.apache.org/documentation/quickstart/openstack/), [Compute Basics](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/tree/master/compute-basics) example, and the [Rackspace Cloud Servers](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/tree/master/rackspace/src/main/java/org/jclouds/examples/rackspace/cloudservers) examples.